# "RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, event-loop

I use [**`loop.close()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.close) in **`test()`** to close **the event loop** as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test(loop):
    print("Test")
    loop.stop() # Stop the event loop
    loop.close() # Here

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.create_task(test(loop))

loop.run_forever()
```

But, I got the error below even though I use [**loop.stop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop) to stop the event loop before [**`loop.close()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.close):

> RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

So, are there any ways to solve the error?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **`loop.close()`** after **`loop.run_forever()`** with **`try:`** and **`finally`:** as shown below, then the error is solved:

```py
import asyncio

async def test(loop):
    print("Test")
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.create_task(test(loop))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close() # Here
```